# Having a problem with the generic template module in Django that won't allow me to run the live server

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, generics

I am trying to learn Django by doing the app on their documentation page, but I have came across an error with the generic templates that I can't figure out at all.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/andrei/Personals/Programming projects/First-Django-App/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
  File "/home/andrei/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/andrei/Personals/Programming projects/First-Django-App/mysite/polls/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/andrei/Personals/Programming projects/First-Django-App/mysite/polls/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    class ResultView(generic.ResultView):
AttributeError: module 'django.views.generic' has no attribute 'ResultView'
```

This is the error the terminal is giving me.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question
# Create your views here.
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "polls/index.html"
    context_object_name = "latest_question_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        "Return the last 5 questions"
        return Question.objects.order_by("-pub_date")[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "polls/detail.html"

class ResultView(generic.ResultView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "polls/result.html"

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

These are my views.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "polls"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/result/', views.ResultView.as_view(), name='result'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

And my URLs if that helps. I think there is a problem with my naming, perhaps I named some file wrong or there is a type somewhere I can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inheriting your `ResultView` from `django.views.generic.ResultView`, which does not exist - I guess you wanted `DetailView` instead. This is what the message at the bottom of the stacktrace tells you about your line 20.

These stacktraces may look scary at first, but they are your friends when debugging and you should read them (bottom to top, usually).